# Elasticsearch: NoClassDefFoundError after installed plugin

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch

I wrote a tokenizer plugin by myself, and compile it with maven successfully. And elasticsearch running well after installed it. But when I try to use it to segment sentences, I get the error message bellow:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/kevinsawicki/http/HttpRequest
    at org.elasticsearch.thulac.MyTokenizer.thulacSeg(MyTokenizer.java:32)
    at org.elasticsearch.thulac.MyTokenizer.<init>(MyTokenizer.java:64)
    at org.elasticsearch.thulac.MyAnalyzer.createComponents(MyAnalyzer.java:12)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.AnalyzerWrapper.createComponents(AnalyzerWrapper.java:113)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer.tokenStream(Analyzer.java:182)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.analyze.TransportAnalyzeAction.shardOperation(TransportAnalyzeAction.java:230)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.analyze.TransportAnalyzeAction.shardOperation(TransportAnalyzeAction.java:60)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.custom.TransportSingleCustomOperationAction$AsyncSingleAction$1.run(TransportSingleCustomOperationAction.java:161)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I use the [kevinsawicki/http-request](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request). Is it because I didn't put the http-request jar into the elasticsearch java path? And if necessary where should I put it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to provide you jar files to the lib folder of elasticsearch.

Where? That depends on where elasticsearch is installed. E.g. use `find / -type d -name elasticsearch` to find the dir. On Centos it's `/usr/share/elasticsearch/`, which contains a `lib` subfolder. Or more comfortable:

- On **Debian**  systems you can use `dpkg -L elasticsearch` and
- on **rpm**-based systems like Centos, RedHat, Suse etc., you can use `rpm -ql elasticsearch` to find out.

Try deploying your code and all dependent libraries in this `lib` folder.

Comment: I installed elasticsearch only by unzip it, and run by `[path_to_elasticsearch] bin/elasticsearch`. And I have tried put the http-request.jar to the elasticsearch/lib folder, but still get the NoClassDefFoundError. Should I install the elasticsearch by another way?

Comment: Is it still the same `NoClassDefFoundError`?

Comment: Yes, and finally I implement the HttpRequest class by another mothod. But it works for the other NoClassDefFoundError, egg Json NoClassDefFound.Thank you.